# Kibana not showing the correct data while choosing with timestamp & received_at

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, kibana-6

I have Below `logstash.conf` file, where i saw the data was processing correctly but today i see very weird issues where indices for `noi-syslog` are not showing the correct `syslog_timestamp` .

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    max_open_files => 64000
    type => "noi-syslog"
  }
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog_CISCO/*/network.log" ]
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    max_open_files => 64000
    type => "apic_logs"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "noi-syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
 }
}
  if [type] == "apic_logs" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} (?<prog>[\w._/%-]+) %{SYSLOG5424SD:fault_code}%{SYSLOG5424SD:fault_state}%{SYSLOG5424SD:crit_info}%{SYSLOG5424SD:log_severity}%{SYSLOG5424SD:log_info} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
 }
}
output {
        if [type] == "noi-syslog" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                manage_template => false
                index => "noi-syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "messages"
  }
 }
}

output {
        if [type] == "apic_logs" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                manage_template => false
                index => "apic_logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "messages"
  }
 }
}
```

### Indices For the `apic_logs` & `noi-syslog`:

```
$ curl -s -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v |  grep apic_logs
green  open   noi-syslog-2019.03.13           Fz1Rht65QDCYCshmSjWO4Q   5   1    6845696            0      2.2gb            1gb
green  open   noi-rmlog-2019.03.13            W_VW8Y1eTWq-TKHAma3DLg   5   1     148613            0     92.6mb           45mb
green  open   apic_logs-2019.03.13            pKz61TS5Q-W2yCsCtrVvcQ   5   1    1606765            0    788.6mb        389.7mb
```

The Kibana page showing correctly all the fields while choosing with @timesatmp  for `apic_logs` Index but not working correctly For Linux system Logs Index `noi-syslog`.

[image]

The `noi-syslog` not showing all the fields while choosing with `@timestamp` however showing `_grokparsefailure` tag, anothering fact is that when choosing `received_at` for the same `noi-syslog` its showing all the fields but not showing the timely data.

Below is the Image showing chosen with `received_at`

[image]

Below is the Image showing chosen with `@timestamp`

[image]

### In the logstash logs:

```
# tail -5 log-cohort_deprecation.log
[2019-03-13T20:16:29,112][WARN ][o.e.d.a.a.i.t.p.PutIndexTemplateRequest] [noida-elk.cadence.com] Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]
[2019-03-13T20:16:30,548][WARN ][o.e.d.a.a.i.t.p.PutIndexTemplateRequest] [noida-elk.cadence.com] Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]
[2019-03-13T20:19:45,935][WARN ][o.e.d.a.a.i.t.p.PutIndexTemplateRequest] [noida-elk.cadence.com] Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]
[2019-03-13T20:19:48,644][WARN ][o.e.d.a.a.i.t.p.PutIndexTemplateRequest] [noida-elk.cadence.com] Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]
[2019-03-13T20:20:13,069][WARN ][o.e.d.a.a.i.t.p.PutIndexTemplateRequest] [noida-elk.cadence.com] Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]
```

### The Memory usage on the System:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32057      31794        263          0        210      18206
-/+ buffers/cache:      13378      18679
Swap:       102399        115     102284
```

Total memory 32GB i have assigned 8GB to each Elastic & Logstash, i doubt if this is causing the issue.

### Work-around for dropping the `grokparsefailure` tag:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "noi-syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
 }
 if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
         drop { }
 }
}
```

### 1- OR an alternative just an idea..

```
filter {
  if [type] == "noi-syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
 }
  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
   }
  }     
 }
}
```

### 2- OR another alternative just an idea..

```
filter {
  if [type] == "noi-syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
 }
  elif "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
   }
   else "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
         drop { }
  }
 }
```

Comment: The problem is in your `grok` filter, it is not parsing your message correctly, the field that you want to use as timestamp, `syslog_timestamp`, depends on the correct parse of the message, if the grok is not working, the field isn't being created. You need to update your question with text samples of the messages that are giving you errors and your grok filters so people can try to reproduce your pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the messages on your examples for the type `noi-syslog` are different from each other and your `grok` filter only works for the first one, when `grok` fails to parse a message it adds a tag named `_grokparsefailure`.

Your first examples that works on `grok` is:

```
Mar 13 15:55:02 hostname /usr/bin/crontab[32708]: (root) LIST (root)
```

The second example that fails grok is:

```
Mar 12 11:01:02 hostname run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3970 starting mcelog.cron
```

This second message is wrong, it is missing a closing bracket (`]`) and a colon (`:`) after the PID `3970`, so your `grok` pattern does not work.

Since your `grok` failed, the field `syslog_timestamp` does not exist, so your `date` filter has nothing to do and `@timestamp` will be set to the time when the event entered the logstash pipeline.

You need to have a `grok` pattern to each pattern of messages you have, one quick way to correct the `syslog_timestamp` is to catch the message who failed grok and apply another `grok` filter to get the `syslog_timestamp` field and the rest of the message in another field.

Try to add the following conditional to your pipeline.

```
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:rest_of_syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "path" ]
   } 
}
```

The result of this `grok` will be like this:

```
{
  "syslog_hostname": "hostname",
  "syslog_timestamp": "Mar 12 11:01:02",
  "rest_of_syslog_message": "run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3970 starting mcelog.cron"
}
```

Comment: leandrojmp, thnx for your valuable answer +1 for that, however i added the workaround by dropping the `grokparsefailure` tag so the other data can be processed but i need to see how i can fit your approach ino my logstash filter.

Comment: You need to fix your `grok`, that's your main problem, you have at the moment two different messages patterns and your grok only works for one of them, you need a grok that works for both or add another patten that works on the second message. My suggestion is to use the conditional above after your grok to get the correct `syslog_timestamp` and create a grok pattern to parse the `rest_of_syslog_message` field.

Comment: Hello @leandrojmp, You are absolutely correct , i have just updated my post with work-around which i applied for time being however i just kept few idea as an edit as well keeping your suggestions in mind, could you please suggest if those doable.

Comment: I think that is better to catch the events that have `_grokparsefailure` than to drop then, this way you still have the message. Your problem is only the `grok`, you need to see how many different patterns of messages do you have and make a `grok` pattern to parse each one of them.